# Specific order of inline-block elements on mobile and desktop devices

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add two square ads to the right of the image on the web-site. The idea is to make this responsive like this:

http://s9.postimg.org/pdecyqi8f/div.png

Is this possible to achieve using CSS?

I use `inline-block` to position ads to the right and `max-width: 100%` to scale the image. I need the support of IE 9+ and mobile browsers.

I tried different approaches, don't even know which code example to show. It is relatively easy to position ads to the right of the image using `inline-block`:

```css
div{
    border: 2px solid;        
}
#img,#container{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#ad1, #ad2{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    color: red;    
}
#img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    max-width: 100%;
    color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="img"> </div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="ad1">ad1</div>
    <div id="ad2">ad2</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w7zfj1ju/

Yet in this case I won't get desired view on narrow screens. Also, since `max-width: 100%;` is used for `#img` this div would cover `#ad1` and `#ad2` on narrow screens.

To achieve desired mobile view I had to change HTML to the following:

```css
div{
    border: 2px solid;
    display: inline-block;    
}
#ad1, #ad2{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    color: red;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    max-width: 100%;
    color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="ad1">ad1</div>
<div id="img"> </div>
<div id="ad2">ad2</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gxnqo8da/

In this case I didn't really know how to position `#ad1` to the right of the `#img`. I gave a try to absolute positioning, it did not work. Flex also seemed not to be an option due to compatibility reasons.

I also tried to use `direction:rtl;` like this:

```css
div{
    border: 2px solid;
    display: inline-block;    
}
#container{
    direction:rtl;
    border: 0px;
}
#ad1, #ad2{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    color: red;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    max-width: 100%;
    color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="ad1">ad1</div>
    <div id="img"> </div>
    <div id="ad2">ad2</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n1mo76bv/

and this:

```css
div{
    border: 2px solid;
    text-align: left;
}
#container{
    direction:rtl;
    border: 0px;    
}
#ad1, #ad2{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    color: red;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    max-width: 100%;
    color: purple;
    display: inline-block;
}
#ad1{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="ad1">ad1</div>
    <div id="img"> </div>
</div>
<div id="ad2">ad2</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w7sknehL/

didn't help much since I could not position `#ad2`.

So, I don't ask to write any code. I'm just desperate for an advice.

Comment: You need to at least attempt a solution and post all relevant code.  We won't write the code for you.

Comment: You can edit the css with '@media'. So when the width of the screen reaches a certain width the css changes. However, you need to make sure, "compatibility mode is turned off".

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support Android 2 and Opera Mini you can still use flexbox to achieve this result via media query. Example below:

```css
.img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
}

.ad {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

@media (min-width : 801px) {
  .wrapper {
    padding-right: 110px;
  }
  .img {
    float: left;
  }   
  .ad {
    clear: right;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -110px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

@media (max-width : 800px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .img {
    order: 2;
    margin: 10px auto;
  }
  .ad {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .ad1 {
    order: 1;
  }
  .ad2 {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img"> </div>
  <div class="ad ad1">ad1</div>
  <div class="ad ad2">ad2</div>
</div>
```

Also:

1. I didn't use browser prefixes for flexbox, so it will not work in all browsers. Add prefixes or use autoprefixer to make it work there.
2. Fix media query parameters for you needs, I only inserted width 800 as example value, real query to detect mobile will differ.

Comment: Alexey, thank you for your answer and code example. Unfortunately, even though I don't need Android 2, Opera Mini accounts for 9.37% of web-site's visitors, so, its support is required.